# How to make VB .NET's AND act as &&

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitwise-operators

I was discussing some of the differences between VB .NET and C# with a co-worker today. He pointed out that && acts as a bitwise operator while VB .NET's AND doesn't always do that. To demonstrate we typed up a bit of code and with VB this should work, but doesn't.

```
Dim a As Draw.Bitmap
Dim b As Draw.Bitmap
If (Not a Is Nothing) And (Not b Is Nothing) Then MsgBox("bang")
' in the above example both NOTs cause the "true" statement to become false, it should       
'trigger the Msgbox
```

I'm trying to come up with a way to make the above statement "work". ANDALSO didn't work for me.

Comment: Your example is really unclear. `Not a Is Nothing` is false, so why would you expect them both being false to mean you get the message box? What is the equivalent C# code you're trying to emulate in VB?

Comment: In the above example, the msgbox should trigger as AND is evaluating




A Is Nothing = True, but NOT'ed makes it FALSE
B Is Nothing = True, but NOT'ed makes it FALSE




So FALSE AND FALSE should trigger MSGBOX, it is not, however.

Comment: No...False And False evaluate to False.  So the And comparison fails.  And only returns true when **both** evaluations return true.

Comment: `False And False` is in fact `False`

Comment: @user1693074: Are you *actually* looking for XOR? Try writing the equivalent C# code and you'll see it behaves exactly like the VB here. Your logic is incorrect.

Comment: Let me rephrase. FALSE and FALSE make the conditional statement true. The MSGBOX should trigger, correct?

Comment: @user1693074 - NO!  FALSE and FALSE makes FALSE.  Only TRUE and TRUE make TRUE.  I think you need another cup of coffee :)

Comment: Probably -- one shouldn't code on 3 hours of sleep...but alas...the perils of employment.

Comment: False AND False = False.! 0 AND 0 = 0, 0 AND 1 = 0, 1 AND 0 = 0, 1 AND 1 = 1 .

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to modify the logic to test for both instances if you needed to check if both were something or both were nothing.

Try this example:

```
 Dim oStart As New Object
 Dim oStop As New Object

 If (oStart IsNot Nothing) And (oStop IsNot Nothing) Then
     MessageBox.Show("Result1")
 ElseIf (oStart Is Nothing) And (oStop Is Nothing) Then
     MessageBox.Show("Result2")
 End If
```

When you run this you should see a message box that shows `Result1`. Now if you were to change the declarations to this:

```
Dim oStart As Object
Dim oStop As New Object
```

Or vice versa then you will not see either message box because neither condition was true.

If you then change the declaration to:

```
Dim oStart As Object
Dim oStop As Object
```

Then you should see a message box that shows `Result2`.

This happens because a logical `AND` only returns true when both sides of the equation are true. In order to accomplish what you are trying to do above, test if both sides are either something or nothing, then you need two checks ensuring that both sides of the `AND` result as true.